# Given a fully linked a.out, which defines symbol foo, how can I tell which object file that definition came from, without relinking the a.out?

Tags: c, symbols, elf

I'm trying to parse an ELF file and create a list of symbols defined in each object file. I am able to find everything I need except for the link between symbols and object files.

I couldn't find anything like that in the ELF specifications. 
In this particular file I'm parsing I have some embedded DWARF debug info I could use, but ideally I would like to find a link between symbols and objects that is standard as I want to apply this for many non GCC compilers.

Comment: The usual case is: you have the symbol defined in one file and listed as undefined in several other files. Then you link the undefined symbols to the defined symbol. There are, however, several special cases of weak defined symbols, which are overridden by strong defined symbols and other things like that. The details are quite complicated

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Is it something `nm object_file.o` and `nm -D stripped_shared_object.so` or `nm -D stripped_binary` wouldn't tell you?

Comment: There is nothing in a program that says which undefined symbols reside in which dynamic library. Each of the libraries is loaded in turn and as many symbols as possible are resolved from that library. This allows library spoofing with LD_PRELOAD, for example. There is a version tag, but that is different. The version tag effectively forces the matcher to find a symbol named symbol@version instead of just symbol, but it still doesn't enforce that version "glib_4" is actually defined by glib.so, and not "intercept_glib.so".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to parse an ELF file and create a list of symbols defined in each object file.

Are you processing *individual* ELF object files, or a fully linked executable or shared library? Since the only way for your question to make sense is the latter, let's assume that your *actual* question is:

**Given a fully linked `a.out`, which defines symbol `foo`, how can I tell which object file that definition came from, without relinking the `a.out`?**.

In general, you can't.

First, not every symbol defined in `a.out` may even come from an object file: some may be defined via a linker script or a `--defsym` command line argument.

Second, *weak* symbols could be defined in multiple object files, and the linker is free to choose any one of them.

Last, there is absolutely no record of object file -> symbol association in the `a.out`. In fact, you can't even extract the list of `.o` files that were linked in (without redoing the link and asking the linker to print them).

You *may* be able to reestablish this association by looking at the debug info, which will tell you what translation unit the symbol came from, and then guess that *probably* `foo.c` was compiled into `foo.o`, but this again may fail as `foo.c` may have been compiled into `bar.o` and `baz.o` (with different `-DFOO` defines).

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. This is exactly what I wanted to ask. The answer is also pretty clear.

Comment: As far as your comment on extracting a list of .o files, when I use readelf, the first symbols in the symbol table are the .c files that were compiled then linked separately. The 'type' reported by readelf is also 'FILE.'

I'm using the GreenHills toolchain for this. With some other compilers the resulting ELF does not contain this information.